# Change the name of an Access query

Tags: ms-access

I have a query. On the left I can rename it. But when I open it I cannot change the title to the top. I have tried looking in the layout and design views. Attached is a screenshot. [image: Query screenshot]

Comment: You cannot rename a query while it is open. You need to close it to rename it.

Comment: To the left I right click MasterReportStatusPrimaryQ - Open Items Kelly. I select rename shortcut and rename it. I saved, closed and reopened Access. This did not change the name of the query when I reopened it. I imagine there is somewhere else it needs to be changed.

Comment: [When you view custom objects in the Navigation Pane, you are actually looking at shortcuts to those objects. An object icon with a small arrow next to its lower-left corner indicates that it is a shortcut or pointer to the actual object.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/View-and-manage-objects-by-using-the-Navigation-Pane-274DFC5A-281B-472B-94E2-EF931C5CC590#bm7)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're not actually changing the name of the query, but a shortcut.

1. At the top of the navigation pane, click the down pointing arrow to
   the right of the text "Custom"Select the option that says "Object Type"
2. Click that down pointing arrow again and select he option that says
   "Queries"
3. Make sure the query is closed
4. Find the query in question and right click it to rename it

Also, why are you hard-coding people into the queries? You should have one query that works for any person and then filters them out based on a parameter, but that's not the question you asked, so I'll leave it at that.

Answer (score 3):

"Shortcut"?

At the left pane, top, select All objects, then select queries, and rename the query itself.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, can you explain it in a different way.

Comment: @Anthony did. Thanks.